# How to apply a function to a column of a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Let's assume that we have a Spark DataFrame

```
df.getClass
Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = class org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

with the following schema

```
df.printSchema
root
|-- rawFV: string (nullable = true)
|-- tk: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Given that each row of the `tk` column is an array of strings, how to write a Scala function that will return the number of elements in each row?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have to write a  custom function because there is one:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.size

df.select(size($"tk"))
```

If you really want you can write an `udf`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val size_ = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => xs.size)
```

or even create custom a expression but there is really no point in that.

Comment: Perfect!   For generality, I would like to know how to apply a UDF to a dataframe.  Could you point me to a simple example?

Comment: There are dozens of examples on SO ([a couple of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1560062+import+org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf+[apache-spark])) and as always source (especially tests) are good place to start.

Comment: How would you use this size_ function?

Comment: Same way as built-in `size` ( `size_($"tk")`).

Comment: What about if I want to define size_ with a def?  I understand it may look like a complete overkill but this way it would be very easy to change to something else.

Comment: Just pass it to the udf wrapper.

Comment: In Spark 1.6.1, I get the following error when using this approach: error: type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.Column required: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[TitleRecs,?] titleRecs.select(size($"sims"))

Answer (score 1):

One way is to access them using the sql like below.

```
df.registerTempTable("tab1")
val df2 = sqlContext.sql("select tk[0], tk[1] from tab1")

df2.show()
```

To get size of array column,

```
val df3 = sqlContext.sql("select size(tk) from tab1")
df3.show()
```

If your Spark version is older, you can use HiveContext instead of Spark's SQL Context.

I would also try for some thing that traverses.