# Applying scala uaparser to a column of dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, udf, ua-parser

How to apply scala uaparser to a column of a dataframe.
Each row in the column in the dataframe is of the form -

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3"

I am trying to something of the form -

```
def getTrnUiEvent(hiveDf:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame): Unit = {
val trnUiEventDf = hiveDf
  .withColumn("application_browser_user_agent", getUAFamily(hiveDf("application_browser_user_agent")))}


 val getUAFamily = udf((ua_string:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) => {
Parser.get.parse(ua_string.toString()).userAgent.family})
```

I am receiving an error for the above. I have also tried other ways to do the above but am ending up the with same result. The thing I cant get my head around is how each row of the dataframe column can be processed by the uaparser.
Each row of hiveDf("application_browser_user_agent") looks like the string example pasted above.

The links I have looked at - 
[Applying function to Spark Dataframe Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227568/applying-function-to-spark-dataframe-column?lq=1)

Do I convert this to an RDD first and then process each row of the RDD using the uaparser?

Link for uaparser - https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-scala

error message -

```
/Users/pojha/github/Bacon/scala/bacon/src/main/scala/baconParallel.scala:62: 


No TypeTag available for String


[error]   val getUAFamily = udf((ua_string:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) => {
```

Comment: add the error message in the question is helpful

Comment: Added the error message as requested.

Comment: I guess you are trying to get the UserAgent from column application_browser_user_agent. If so, then the udf should be String => String, while you are trying to from DataFrame to ?

Comment: That was my initial definition for the udf.

` val getUAFamily = udf[org.uaparser.scala.Client,String]((ua_string:String) => {
    Parser.get.parse(ua_string)
  })`

`scala:62: No TypeTag available for String
[error]   val getUAFamily = udf[org.uaparser.scala.Client,String]((ua_string:String) => {`

Comment: Your initial definition seems to work for me.

Comment: Have you solved this? I am trying to do the same thing. I tried this - `val getUAFamily = udf[org.uaparser.scala.Client,String]((ua_string) => { Parser.default.parse(ua_string) })`,  `val newdf = df.withColumn("new_user_agent", getUAFamily('user_agent))` . But I am getting something like this - [[Mobile Safari,8...]]. I am trying to get the device, browser and OS actually.